# What to do with old photo paper

Tags: black-and-white, paper

I am doing some spring cleaning and have discovered (well I sort of knew they were there) at the back of a cupboard the following un-exposed B&W white papers:

- Ilford 5x7 Pearl Multigrade IV RC Deluxe. 100 count, un-opened.
- Ilford 8x10 Glossy Multigrade IV FB Fiber. 25 count, but opened.
- Ilford 8x10 Satin Multigrade IV RC Deluxe. 25 count, but opened.

These all date from the late 90's. Are the usable?  Should they simply be binned?   Or would they make for some interesting effects for someone so inclined to actually use them?

Comment: One experiment is worth a thousand expert opinions.— Bill Nye, the science guy.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are good that the papers only have lost some sensitivity or contrast and that you with some adaption in exposure and gradiation control can make good prints on them.

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use them, consider donating them to a camera group or a local school's art department.  I donated a bunch of 20-yr old paper to my local school (they do have a film course & darkroom), and they found the paper worked fine.

Answer (score -3):

try using them for lumen printing

Comment: Perhaps a link to what lumen printing is would make this answer more helpful.